# TreeWalker, textNodes and RTL ordering in natural language web pages

Tags: javascript, dom, internationalization, right-to-left

In languages like Arabic text direction is right-to-left. For an example go to the facebook homepage and select Arabic from the languages link at the bottom of the screen.

My question is if I am using tree walker to step through the child nodes of an element containing some arabic text, and I put the textContent of those nodes into an array, and concatenate it, will the textNodes have been ordered in the semantically correct order (RTL) or will they be mixed up?

Another way of asking the question is : do I need to do my own RTL checking if stepping through text Nodes in an international environment, or will the browser's tree walker take care of everything for me ( roughly speaking document order == semantic order ).

I am not an expert on DOM textNodes in i18n, RTL or these issues, and the purpose of the text node traversal is data collection.